# Website built with Backbone and React(with bower) is using developer version of react. How to make it use prod version?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bower, yarnpkg

The web application i'm working on is built with Backbone and many components are built with React.

When i use React developer tool, it says : 'This page is using the development build of React.Note that the development build is not suitable for production. Make sure to use the production build before deployment.'

Under the 'dependencies' section in bower.json, "react": "v0.14.2" is specified.

I believe that this should have picked the prod version, since there is a separate 'devDependencies' section in the same file for picking the dev version.

I read that its possible to configure dev/prod versions of react in webpack. But i'm not using webpack. Is there a way to do it with just bower/yarn?

EDIT 1:

0.14.2 comes with react.js and react-with-addons.js. The latest version however has react.development.js and react.production.js.

I tried using the min.js version and don't see the message that i'm using a dev version anymore. :)